# Is there a separate bathroom for prefect boys and girls at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

In the fourth year Harry goes to the Prefects' Bathroom. Was this bathroom shared equally by male and female prefects or were there separate bathrooms?

Comment: it's a "bath" more in the sense of a Roman Bath, as in "let's go bathe" - ie, a swimming pool / hot tub sort of scene.

Comment: @Fattie I’m not convinced: there’s soaps, and he went on in the nude...

Comment: Is the subject of prefect bathrooms suddenly in the news or something? I feel like I must be missing something.

Comment: @Tim - those are good points

Comment: @Tim Using soaps and going in the nude is an apt description of a Roman (or middle age European) bath house.

Comment: If there were two of them, they would not be written with the initial letters in capitals.

Answer (score 13):

No, the Prefects' Bathroom appears to be for both boys *and* girls. Hermione explicitly states that she can use it.

> The day after this rather gloomy birthday tea, their letters and book lists arrived from Hogwarts. Harry’s included a surprise: he had been made Quidditch Captain. ‘That gives you equal status with prefects!’ cried Hermione happily. ‘You can use **our special bathroom** now, and everything!’
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*</sup></sub>

It's not immediately apparent whether the bath is intended for mixed use(!!!!), but Head Girls, [female?] prefects and [female?] Quidditch captains would appear to all have access.

> [image: Screenshot from Harry Potter Hogwarts Mystery showing Bill giving two female students a tour of the Prefects' Bathroom, he says: It can only be used by Prefects, Head Girls and Boys, and Quidditch Captains.]
>
> <sub><sup>[*Harry Potter Hogwarts Mystery: In the Prefect's Bathroom*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-cAITdkuDQ)</sup></sub>

Comment: The "bath" seems more like a swimming pool than what we'd normally think of as a bath.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It's a [communal bath](https://images.app.goo.gl/hUQLNYqmodhXBUYAA) like schools used to have. But kicked up a notch with added whimsy.

Comment: Notably, Harry encounters Moaning Myrtle in this location, which if I recall is where she was killed (it's implied that she has to stick around that room because of that), so that right there is at least one boy and one girl who have definitely used that room, if not both living at the same time.  (And that's in the book, which I think is maybe more canonical than the video games?)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - Moaning Myrtle was killed in a different bathroom; https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Moaning_Myrtle%27s_Bathroom

Comment: Okay, I guess she can move around then, as she was definitely in the prefect's bathroom - odd that she seems to only be seen in bathrooms, does she travel via the plumbing or something?  Eh, ghosts, magic, whatever.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - That is precisely out how she travels around. Even down to occasionally getting flushed out into the lake when she's not paying enough attention